# ProfileLooter returns AttributeError in InstaLooter library

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was referring the [docs](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/instalooter/latest/instalooter.pdf) provided by InstaLooter at page 21 section 5.1 Download pictures

If I run the code provided I get the following error no matter what I do

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Code\temp\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    looter = ProfileLooter("instagram")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\instalooter\looters.py", line 705, in __init__
    super(ProfileLooter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pack  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\instalooter\_utils.py", line 94, in get_shared_data
    return json.loads(match.group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I have installed instalooter globally and have also tried using a virtual environment but the same problem is occuring

I tried using the if condition to check if the parameter is None but still the same error

The Code:

```py
from instalooter.looters import ProfileLooter
looter = ProfileLooter("instagram")
```

With if condition:

```py
from instalooter.looters import ProfileLooter
id = 'instagram'
if id not None:
    looter = ProfileLooter("instagram")
```

Obviously this isn't my actual code but I was able to recreate the same issue in the code that the documentation provides

I tried checking for None type, reinstalling instalooter and changing environments